# How to randomly pick number of 2 numbers. p5js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I think it is a very simple question, but I can't find an answer. How to randomly pick one number out of 2 numbers. In my situation, I need to pick numbers {-2, 2}. Just one out of these two numbers.

Comment: in p5.js you can do `random([-2, 2])`

Comment: ... see [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of items into `random()` if you need to randomly choose from a predetermined set.

In your case, the following code will always pick (**-2** or **2**), nothing else or anything in-between.

```
random([-2, 2]);
```

You can read more about the random function here https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random

Answer (score 0):

When you needs to get same random value for all clients at the same time (so all clients will get the same random value without having to talk over the network), you can use [randomSeed()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomSeed) as pseudo-random numbers generator (PRNG).